# How to dynamically set TextView size -- android

Tags: android, performance

How to dynamically set the textview size. I have textview with max length of 3. I want to maximize the middle of character than rest of character. How to set the textview size dynamically, I used the looping concept and display through characAt(index). but this is not giving me a exact answer. Can anyone guide me on this . thanks in advance.

Comment: `tv.setTextSize(floatvalue)` or use a spannblestring

Comment: divide the text character by character in 3 textviews and then probably you can do it better.

Answer (score 1):

Just go this [link](http://eazyprogramming.blogspot.jp/2013/06/spannable-string-in-android-url-span.html) is enough.

Using [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) in your TextView.